# HTML: Form with dynamic drop-downs based on if/else? (newbie question)

Tags: html, dynamic, dropdownbox

I'm new to all this, so sorry for what is probably a basic question.

I've created a form to generate an email and want the user to select from an initial drop-down and then have a subsequent drop-down being related to the first entry. It's football-related so if the user selects "League A" I want them to see in the next drop down "Team 1", "Team 2" and if they select "League B" I want "Team 3", "Team 4" etc.

I'm happy to hard code these as they don't change often but although I've managed to create the form and dropdowns, I can't get the If (condition) statement to work. Not sure if I just don't have the right approach or I'm doing something that just isn't possible.

I'm assuming I could just use the logic if (dropdown1="League A") then  dropdown2 options are Team 1, Team 2, ELSE then repeat from dropdown2 etc.

Any suggestions, please?
Thanks
Ian

```
Code added:
<label for="Age Group">Age Group:</label>
<select id="agegroup" name="Age Group">
<option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
<option value="Under 7">Under 7</option>
<option value="Under 8">Under 8</option>
<option value="Under 9">Under 9</option>
<option value="Under 10">Under 10</option>
</select>
<Br>

if (agegroup==="Under 7"){
<label for="under7">Under 7:</label>
<select id="under7" name="Under 7">
<option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
<option value="Team A">Team A</option>
<option value="Team B">Team B</option>
</select>
<Br>
;}

else if (agegroup==="Under 8"){
<label for="under 8">Under 8:</label>
<select id="under8" name="under 8">
<option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
<option value="Team C">Team C</option>
<option value="Team D">Team D</option>
</select>
<Br>
;}
```

Comment: What solution are you using for the backend? You can't have conditionals in the HTML itself per se, but if you're using PHP/javascript/etc to generate the HTML code, you can conditionally render whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Joel, it's php based. I've basically taken over a website for a charity and the person who wrote it was a proper developer but has literally dumped it.
Basically what you are saying it that what I want to work won't work, so I need to have some background data i.e. like a text file? and then call them via a query (js?)? Thank you

Comment: Well, it's that HTML itself does not handle conditional data. It's just a markup language. PHP would be your 'interpreter' - Meaning you could have conditionals there. Can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks Joel, this is what I have so far:

Comment: Did you add something? Also - is this file a php file?

Comment: Yes I did to the original post in the “code” section, and yes it’s a php file

Comment: You need to wrap your conditionals in PHP tags: (e.g. `<?php (code goes here) ?>`

Comment: Sorry this is just an extract, the page itself has all the relevant tags and works fine as a php web page.  Where I am struggling is knowing how to structure the condition i.e. if select id="agegroup" equals "Under 7" then show the relevant drop down values in select id = "under7".

Comment: You have php conditionals inside of HTML with no tags. I don't think this is working the way you're thinking it does. This is usually how you do it: `<?php if (cond): ?> <div>thing1</div> <?php endif; ?>` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Alternatively, could I use JS to on the change event of the first drop down to set values of up to 30 variables which would then become the dropdown values?